# Proving that the maximum of two convex functions is also convex

Tags: calculus

Here's a homework question I'm struggling with:

> Let $f,g$ two convex functions. Prove that $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is
> also convex

I don't know where to begin. The only thing I had in mind was was to try proving that if a function is convex on two sets $A$ and $B$, it is also convex on their union. That does not seem right though, for example, if I glue together $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=\frac{x^2}{1000}$ where $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$ and $g$ on $(1,2]$.

Anyway, that was the only thing I thought about. Any better ideas? thanks!

Comment: @yotamoo: While typesetting, use `\max` instead of `max` (similarly use `\sin` instead of `sin` etc)

Comment: @Didier Can you add that as an answer adding, probably another line or two, so that this question gets an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the characterization that $h$ is convex if and only if, for every $t$ in $[0,1]$ and every $(x,y)$, $h(tx+(1-t)y)\leqslant th(x)+(1-t)h(y)$.

**Second hint:** One wants to prove that $h(z)\leqslant th(x)+(1-t)h(y)$ where $z=tx+(1-t)y$. Since $h=\max\{f,g\}$, this is equivalent to the two inequalities
$$
f(z)\leqslant th(x)+(1-t)h(y),\qquad g(z)\leqslant th(x)+(1-t)h(y).
$$
Consider the first inequality. By convexity of $f$, one knows that $f(z)\leqslant tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$. Furthermore, $f(x)\leqslant$ $____$ and $f(y)\leqslant$ $____$, hence...

Comment: Okay I can assume that $h=g$ at  $tx_1+(1-t)x_2$, but the behavior of $h$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$ has four different options, depending on what function is greater at these points. How can I come to a conclusion?

Comment: Nevermind I saw it, thanks!

Comment: What about the case $ \max_{i} {x}_{i} - \min_{i} {x}_{i} $?

Comment: @Royi If you have a new problem (which frankly I did not get), please post a new question.

Comment: @Did, I fixed an error I had there.

Answer (score 31):

The hint of @Did solves the problem, but there is another proof, which is more intuitive I think.

A function is convex if and only if the area above its graph is convex. But then, the region above $h(x) = \max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is the intersection of the area above $f$ and the region above $g$. Moreover, intersection of convex sets is convex, and that concludes the proof.

Comment: Does this apply similarly for the maximum of two concave functions?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Not really, take for example $f(x) = -(x-2)(x-4)$ and $g(x) = -(x+2)(x+4)$, then $h(-4) = h(-2) = h(2) = h(4) = 0$, but $h(-3) = h(3) = 1$, hence $h$ is not concave.

Comment: @dtldarek is it equivalent to saying that minimum of two concave sets is concave?

Comment: @kaka Yes, you can just use $h(x) = -\max\{-f(x),-g(x)\}$.

Comment: @dtldarek so $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are considered concave and not convex in $h(x)=-\operatorname{max}\{ -f(x),-g(x)\}$ ?

Comment: @kaka If $f$ is concave, then $-f$ is convex.

Comment: Just a short note: the area above the graph is called "epigraph" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)