# $\max_{i\in \{1,...,M\}} (a_i+ r_i)$ strictly convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

For any $r\equiv(r_1,...,r_M)\in \mathbb{R}$, consider the function $$a\equiv(a_1,...,a_M) \in \mathbb{R}^M\mapsto G(a)\equiv \max_{i\in \{1,...,M\}} (a_i+ r_i)$$

Is $G$ strictly convex or convex? Could you help me to show it?

Comment: it's definitely convex, I don't think it's strictly convex though.

Comment: Any proof for non strict convexity @TonyS.F.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum of convex functions is convex.

[See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147475/proving-that-the-maximum-of-two-convex-functions-is-also-convex)

Since $\phi_i(a)=a_i+r_i$ is convex for every $i$, then $G(a)=\max \{\phi_i(a)\} $ is convex.

Consider $M=1$ and $r=0$, since $G(a)=a$, $G$ is not strictly convex.

Comment: Thank you very much. Two clarifications: 1) $\phi_i$ is linear and hence convex and concave, correct? 2) $G(a)=a$ implies $G$ not strictly convex because it is a linear function (hence convex and concave), correct?

Comment: $\phi_i$ is affine, but that does not change the conclusion. You are correct.