# Integral of a convex function is convex?

Tags: integration, optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^M$ with $M\geq 2$.

Consider the function $$a\equiv(a_1,...,a_M) \in \mathbb{R}^M\mapsto G(a)\equiv \int_{\{r\equiv (r_1,..., r_M)\in \mathcal{R}\}} \
\Big[\max_{i\in \{1,...,M\}} (a_i+ r_i)\Big] f(r) dr $$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is

- strictly positive on $\mathcal{R}$ and zero on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathcal{R}$
- $\int_{\{r\equiv (r_1,..., r_M)\in \mathcal{R}\}} f(r) dr =1$

Is $G$ convex? Is it strictly convex? Could you help me to show it? I know that the function within the square brackets is convex but not strictly convex (as kindly explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795529/max-i-in-1-m-a-i-r-i-strictly-convex))

Comment: The integral is a convex combination of the functions within the square brackets, hence, convex.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about strict convexity? Are there stronger conditions on $f$ that can ensure strict convexity (even though, the function within the square brackets is not strictly convex)?

Comment: Also, would convexity hold for ANY function $f$ (not necessarily with the properties described above)?

Comment: It is easy to prove that the integral is convex for any $f\ge 0$. However, strict convexity is problematic here. For example, if the set $R$ is bounded then the integral cannot be strictly convex.